# PHP OCI_BIND_BY_NAME NOT WORKING

Tags: php, bind, oracle-call-interface

The following binding is not working? it prevents event the previous outputs.

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':CONTRACT', 'BC');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':TAX_REGIME_DB', 'VAT');
```

The following one is working

```
  $contract = 'BC';
  $vat = 'VAT';

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':CONTRACT', $contract);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':TAX_REGIME_DB', $vat);
```

please can anybody tell me what the difference is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`oci_bind_by_name()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) expects a *variable reference* as its third argument, so your static string value is not a valid argument.  You *must* bind a variable as a third argument.  That's why your second example does work.

You'll need to place your strings into variables and bind those just as you did in the second case.

[The function prototype:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

```
bool oci_bind_by_name ( resource $statement , string $bv_name , mixed &$variable [, int $maxlength = -1 [, int $type = SQLT_CHR ]] )
```

I would recommend turning up error reporting and enabling `display_errors`. You should probably be seeing warnings about the argument expecting a reference. Always do this in development:

```
; In php.ini
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On

// Or at runtime
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: thank you Michael.. can you also please help me about my related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911270/php-oci-bind-by-name-in-foreach-not-working